# Why does the JComboBox ignore null value states?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a `JComboBox` with a `DefaultComboBoxModel` of these `Integer`s:

```
{null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Say I have `5` in my `JComboBox` and I click on the `JComboBox` and select `2`, then the program below will dispay:

```
5 ->
-> 2
```

Here is the program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JComboBox<Integer> cb = new JComboBox<>();
        cb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new Integer[]{null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}));
        cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                switch (e.getStateChange()) {
                    case ItemEvent.DESELECTED:
                        out.format("%s ->\n", e.getItem());
                        break;
                    case ItemEvent.SELECTED:
                        out.format(" -> %s\n", e.getItem());
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        final JFrame win = new JFrame();
        win.setBounds(800,400,30,70);
        win.add(cb);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What is not clear to me, is why when the value is initially `null` (and it is, as it's the first value in the model's array), the output is

```
 -> 3
```

Meaning the `ItemListener` was called once, only with an `ItemEvent.SELECTED` state. Why wasn't it called with an `ItemEvent.DESELECTED` for the `null` (e.g. printing `null ->`), as with numbers?

It goes the other way too, if I initially had `5` in the `JComboBox` and I selected the empty value (i.e. `null`), then all I see in the console is:

```
5 ->
```

So why does the `JComboBox` ignore `null` value states? [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) doesn't seem to say anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you say is true, what i can see is that in `JCombobox` class in `setSelectedItem` method:

```
if (anObject != null && !isEditable()) {
            // For non editable combo boxes, an invalid selection
            // will be rejected.
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getSize(); i++) {
                E element = dataModel.getElementAt(i);
                if (anObject.equals(element)) {
                    found = true;
                    objectToSelect = element;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

it does not set `objectToSelect`.

So in `DefaultComboBoxModel` implementation `setSelectedItem` method passes null and it does not call `fireContentsChanged` event.